# Division without direct division.

Tags: soft-question, advice

I don't know much about math, that's why I came here to ask for help.
Recently I stumbled in a problem where I have to divide X by Y with specific condition that forbids from doing it directly.

---

To be exact, while the rules allow to perform any action to X **or** Y with the exception of P.S; the only action that can be performed between X **and** Y is addition.
The only way I see to do it is an equation, that I'm not even sure exists. Example for multiplication is:

$$X*Y=\frac{(X+Y)^2-X^2-Y^2}{2}$$

If there's a way then I'll be grateful.

---

P.S. In case that square root cannot be calculated by a formula it cannot be used, also fractions aren't allowed, since they just get cut, while negative numbers are allowed.

Comment: What are X and Y?  Positive integers (naturals)? Any Integers? Rationals? Reals? Also: your multiplication example includes a division by 2. And squaring involves multiplication (by self) Can your division algorithm include multiplication? Your conditions are unclear.

Comment: Anyway, if $X$ and $Y$ are non-zero integers, then just take their absolute values first (to get naturals). Multiplication is just serial addition. Division is just serial subtraction with a running count until you get a non-negative value strictly less than the divisor. At that point, the quotient is the count and the remainder is the value less than the divisor. Signs can be imposed using simple boolean logic after this process. You can use this process with rationals as well after multiplying by the appropriate integers to render the numerator and denominator as integers and so forth.

Comment: But general reals are far trickier to handle.

Comment: You'd better as about "division with addition only", though your example for multiplication cheats, as it uses squares.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to take reciprocals (one divided by a number), then you can substitute $Y = 1/Y$ and you will get

$$\frac{X}{Y} = \frac 1 2 \left(\left(X+\frac{1}{Y}\right)^2 - X^2 - \frac{1}{Y^2}\right)$$

If this is not allowed, you can for example use some iterative method with companion matrices for the polynomial equation $$p(q) = X-Yq=0$$which has root $$q = \frac{X}{Y}$$

You don't even need to do companion matrices, it will suffice to hunt for "multiplicative friends of basis".

For example, using base $2$ and we want to divide $5$ by $3$ and we make the approximation $3^2 = 9 \approx 8$

Then $5/3 = \text{multiply 3 both up and down} = 15/9\approx 15/8 = 1.111$ in binary.

Another $5/3 = \text{multiply 5 both up and down} = 25/15 \approx 25/16 = 1+9/16 = 1.1001$ in binary.

Now what might be more natural for us humans is to use base 10.

Mul with 3 up and down: $5/3 = 15/9 \approx 15/10 = 1.5$

Mul with 33 up and down : $5/3 = 5\cdot 33/99 \approx 165/100 = 1.65$

Comment: If you can take reciprocals.

Comment: @Ian yes, that must be allowed for this to work.

Comment: @mathreadler I've edited the question. Now it should be clearer and better.